# SaveChanges takes anywhere from 40 to 60 seconds to save ~8000 context changes

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

Setup:

- Entity Framework 4 with lazy loading enabled (model-first, table-per-hierarchy).
- Number of table is about 40 (and no table has more than 15-20 fields).
- SQL Server Express 2008 (not r2).
- No database triggers or any other stuff like this exist - it is only used for storage. All the logic is in the code.
- Database size at the moment is approx 2gb.
- (Primary keys are Guids and are generated in code via `Guid.NewGuid()` - if this matters)
- Saving a complex operation result (which produces a complex object graph) takes anywhere from 40 to 60 seconds (the number returned by `SaveChanges` is approx. 8000 - mostly added objects and a some modified).
- Saving the same operation result with an empty (or an almost empty) database usually takes around 1 seconds on the same computer.

The only variable that seems to affect this issue is the database size. But please note that I am only measuring the `Context.SaveChages()` call (so even if I have some weird sluggish queries somewhere that should not affect this issue).

Any suggestions as to why this operation may last this long are appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

Just to clarify - the code that takes 40-60 seconds to execute is (it takes this long only when the DB size is around 2gb):

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
int count = objectContext.SaveChanges(); // this method is not overridden
Debug.Write(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // prints out 40000 - 60000 ms
Debug.Write(count); // I am testing with exactly the same operation and the
                    // result always gives the same count for it (8460)
```

The same operation with an empty DB takes around 1000 ms (while still giving the same count - 8460). Thus the question would be - how could database size affect `SaveChanges()`?

**Update 2**

Running a perf profiler shows that the main bottleneck (from "code perspective") is the following method:

```
Method:   static SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync
Called:    3251 times
Avg:         10.56 ms
Max:        264.25 ms
Min:          0.01 ms
Total:    34338.51 ms
```

**Update 3**

There are non-clustered indexes for all PKs and FKs in the database. We are using random Guids as surrogate keys (not sequential) thus fragmentation is always at very high levels. I tried testing executing the operation in question right after rebuilding all DB indexes (fragmentation was less than 2-3% for all indexes) but it did not seems to improve the situation in any way.

In addition I must say that during the operation in question one table involved in the process has approximately 4 million rows (this table gets lots of inserts). SQL Profiler shows that inserts to that table can last anywhere from 1 to 200 ms (this is a "spike"). Yet again, it does not seem that this changes in case indexes are freshly rebuilt.

In any case - it seems (at the moment) that the problem is on the SQL Server side of the application since the main thing taking up time is that `SNIReadSync` method. Correct me if I am being completely ignorant.

Comment: It must be your loop inside the second query using the primary key index on table...oh wait, that was a guess as I could not see your code or database structure.

Comment: Using nonsequential GUID's could harm performance on inserts, but that should not happen unless the table is quite big (> 1 million records as a guess, could be less).

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Did you actually read the question? What code do you want to see? Reflected `ObjectContext.SaveChages()`? Because that is the line that is slow (according to the stopwatch surronding it). Posting the whole database structure is quite problematic too as it is quite complex (just imagine 10-15 tables with all possible kinds of relations between them). Anything in particular that you need to know about? Check out the last two bullets - that is the strange part of my problem. Why does time of SaveChanges() exec time increase with increased DB size?

Comment: @leppie Yeah, I guess that using Guids should not affect execution time that much.

Comment: My point was really this is an exercise in performance and only you can fully understand your systems and where the performance bottleneck exists - is there some table that simply needs an index for example - break the system down and then do a discovery on each pocket of your system - I did not mean to insult with a flippant comment, only to point out what I state here.  Run some SQL performance monitoring while this occurs to see where you have needs.

Comment: I wonder, IF you have access to a full sql server edition, what the performance would look like in a test scenario.

Comment: Well, I obviously do not hope for a answer like you gave in the first comment. I guess the expected type of reaction was "what aspect of this system to inspect first" or "there is a big issue in EF with databases that have lots of *** relationships" and so on. Thanks for your input, I will see what I can find out with profilers.

Comment: When I have had performance issues with EF I have performed a profiler trace just before I run the SaveChanges. In the trace you will see lots of insert statements. You could take one of these statements and try running it in your 2 scenarios (empty DB and large DB) in SSMS. Have Set Statistics Time and Statistics IO turned on and capture the Query Execution Plan. These should give you a starter on what the issues are. You could even post the results here if you are still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

It hard to guess without profiler, but 8000 of records is definitely too many. Usually EF 4 works ok with up to couple of hundreds objects. I would not be surprised if it turns that change tracking takes most of this time. EF 5 and 6 have some performance optimizations, so if you cannot decrease number of tracked objects somehow, you could experiment with them.

Comment: Well... again, the thing is that the same amount of changes takes ±1-2 seconds to execute when the database is empty. It only takes this much time when the database grows. And that is what I do not understand. Though your point about using a profiler is valid - that is something I need to still check out. I though that maybe someone knows something about the relation of database size to the time it takes to call `SaveChanges` (maybe a known issue or something similar).

Comment: @Jefim The relation of database size to the time it takes to call `SaveChanges` probably has less to do with EF and more to do with how your database is set up. What are your indexes? What type of indexes are they (clustered/non-clustered)? Indexes can have some rather huge implications on performance when it comes to inserts. How many records do you have in your non-empty database?

Comment: Every table has a surrogate Guid PK (non-clustered index) and all FKs are also non-clustered indexes. Of course the fact that we are using Guids means that index fragmentation is always horrible. One of the tables involved in the operation contains ~4 million rows. Other tables have considerably less rows (in tens of thousands). And the operation performance does not improve in any way after an index rebuild (when fragmentation is not more that 2-3% for every index in the DB).